# locally created alias not being used if called using backticks (`)

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I have come across this issue while trying to build up a script to do grep on multiple files for 10 different word.

The script I created, is (minified)

```
#!bin/bash
alias grep='grep -n'
out=`grep word $1`
```

Output

```
some text word  
some other text word more text
```

The grep does work, but the alias is not being considered. It just outputs the matching lines and not the line numbers (`-n` is for line numbers)

and now if i run the below, it works fine

```
#!bin/bash
out=`grep -n word $1`
```

Output and the expected output from above script:

```
233: some text word  
532: some other text word more text
```

I have grep statement at many places in the script, and i don't want to go and edit each line. I am looking to override the grep once by aliasing it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What could be the issue here? How can i make the alias work?

Comment: Aliases are *only* for interactive use (and even in this role, they should only be used in the simplest cases). They also obscure what you are actually calling: use functions (can be exported) or, in this case, keep the arguments in another variable (just like Makefiles do).

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480642/cant-use-alias-within-backticks-inside-bash-script

Answer (score 3):

You forgot this line:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias grep='grep -n'
out=$(grep word "$1")
echo "$out"
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you made an alias for your actual shell. When you use backticks (or `$(...)`), you run a sub-shell which ignores your alias (AFAIK aliases can't be exported, so you'd have to re-define them in the sub-shell).

In your case, maybe the best approach would be to set a variable containing the command. Say:

```
MY_GREP="grep -n"
out=`${MY_GREP} word $1`
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. The backticks create a subshell which inherits its parent's aliases. A subshell is a replica of its parent, it is not a new, separate script.